# array matching count one less than expected

Tags: php

`$ar` is a sock of pairs. `$n` is the number of items in `$ar`. I have to match each number in the array with another if any of them match, its a pair. I have to then return the count of matched items. I have done it below but the answer is one less than what it should be. Example

```
n:9

ar: 10 20 20 10 10 30 50 10 20
```

I get output 2 instead of 3.

```
function sockMerchant($n, $ar) {
    $pair =0;
    $j=0;
    for($i=0; $i< count($ar); $i++)
    {
        for($j=$i+1; $j< count($ar); $j++)
        {
            if ( isset( $ar[$j]) && isset( $ar[$i])) {
                if ($ar[$i]== $ar[$j])
                {
                    unset($ar[$i]);
                    unset($ar[$j]);
                    $pair+=1;
                    $i=0;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return  count($ar);
}
```

Comment: unset $ar[$j] BEFORE $ar[$i], because its always greater

Comment: i think it is a bad idea looping over an array and deleting items in that loop

Answer (score 2):

Instead of what you are doing there is shortcut to achieve the same,

```
$temp = array_count_values($arr); // count number of occurences
echo count(array_filter($temp, function($value){ // filter in not greater than 1 
    return $value > 1;
}));
```

The above snippet will give you all the pairs which are not only once.

Here is an one more alternative for your snippet,

```
$temp = array_count_values($arr); // count number of occurences
$e    = array_reduce($temp, function ($carry, $item) {
    $carry += ($item > 1 ? intval($item / 2) : 0);
    return $carry;
});
echo $e;die;
```

Working [demo](https://3v4l.org/C5EUX).

Comment: Shouldn't you divide `$value` by 2 in order to get the number of pairs?

Comment: I am actually solving hackerrank challenges and stuck in this problem. Writing your solution could solve it but I am trying to understand why my logic doesnt work.

Comment: 20 is coming thrice, I thought of it before. So

Comment: @FahadUddin Why `unset` resetting again `i` to 0, can't you just catch matching pairs, that's it? why are you making it complicated?

Answer (score 0):

If you want total matched pair count then you should return `$pair`. But you are returning `count($ar)` which can not be correct in all the possible scenarios. Check the below code with output and new set of data:

```
<?php
function sockMerchant($n, $ar) {
    $pair =0;
    $j=0;
    for($i=0; $i< $n; $i++)
    {
        for($j=$i+1; $j< $n; $j++)
        {
            if ( isset( $ar[$j]) && isset( $ar[$i])) {
                if ($ar[$i]== $ar[$j])
                {
                    unset($ar[$j]);
                    unset($ar[$i]);
                    $pair+=1;
                    $i=0;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($ar);
    return  $pair.'--'.count($ar);
}

$a = [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20, 80, 40];
$n = 11;
$b = sockMerchant($n, $a);

var_dump($b);

// Output:
/*
Array
(
    [5] => 30
    [6] => 50
    [8] => 20
    [9] => 80
    [10] => 40
)
string(4) "3--5"
*/

?>
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/rU7sk)

Comment: I did that for the reason to check how many arrays were left afterwards. It gave me answer 5 instead of 3.

Comment: But it worked well for me. Check the demo I've attached in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ar = [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20];

$pairIndex = [];
$count = 0;

foreach ($ar as $key => $item) {
    // Start comparing from the next element
    for ($i = ($key + 1); $i < count($ar); $i++) {
        if ($item == $ar[$i] && !in_array($key, $pairIndex)) {
            $pairIndex[] = $key;
            $pairIndex[] = $i;
            $count++;
        }
    }
}

echo "Pairs: " . $count;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the number of pairs.

```
$arr = array(10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20);

$counts = array_count_values($arr); // count number of occurences
array_walk($counts, function(&$x) {$x = intdiv($x, 2);}); //divide each element
    //by 2 (integer division), so now you have pairs of each element
echo array_sum($counts); //sum the pairs
```

Using your initial array, it echoes 3.

Answer (score 0):

simple example what happens to your array:

```
$ar = array(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 , 60, 70, 80, 90);
$lnPointer = 2;
print_r($ar);
// Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 10 [2] => 20 [3] => 30 [4] => 40 [5] => 50 [6] => 60 [7] => 70 [8] => 80 [9] => 90 ) 
echo "<HR>";
echo $ar[$lnPointer];
echo "<HR>";
unset( $ar[$lnPointer]);
print_r($ar);
// Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 10 [3] => 30 [4] => 40 [5] => 50 [6] => 60 [7] => 70 [8] => 80 [9] => 90 ) 
echo "<HR>";
echo $ar[$lnPointer];
```

after unsetting you get an undefined index